# Unable to add product to cart whose price difference is more than 50

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to add prodcut to cart whose original and discounted price differece is more than 50. i have tried with below code.it is calculating the price difference but not click on the item.

can someone please help to find out solution
Also,attachimh images here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ67F.png)

```
getting error when apply logic of calculating difference>>>
======================================
package Tekbakertest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class Ted_sale {
static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger");
     Thread.sleep(2000);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
    prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false); 
      options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://www.tedbaker.com/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")));

            if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")).isDisplayed())
                {

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")).click();

                }
    Actions act=new Actions(driver);
    WebElement Category=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='categories_nav']/li[1]/a"));
   WebElement Sales_clothng=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='categories_nav']/li[1]/nav/div[1]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[3]/a"));
     act.moveToElement(Category).moveToElement(Sales_clothng).click().build().perform();
   Thread.sleep(2000);
      List<WebElement> Product_list=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='name']"));
      System.out.println(Product_list.size());
      for(int i=0;i<Product_list.size();i++)
      {
           List<String> Product_list_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        Product_list_lst.add(Product_list.get(i).getText());
       System.out.println(Product_list.get(i).getText());
         }
            for (WebElement items_product : Product_list)
    {
        System.out.println(items_product.getText());

        }
   System.out.println("Originanal Price of items");
   List<WebElement> Original_price=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='price previous']"));
   System.out.println(Original_price.size());
      for(int i=0;i<Original_price.size();i++)
   {
           List<String> Original_price_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
       Original_price_lst.add(Original_price.get(i).getText());
       System.out.println(Original_price.get(i).getText());
         }
      System.out.println("Discounted Price of items");
   List<WebElement> Discounted_price=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='price unit']"));
   System.out.println(Discounted_price.size());
   for(int i=0;i<Original_price.size();i++)
   {
           List<String> Discounted_price_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
       Discounted_price_lst.add(Discounted_price.get(i).getText());
       System.out.println(Discounted_price.get(i).getText());
   }
  for(int i=0;i<Discounted_price.size();i++)
  {
      List<String> Original_price_lst_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> Discounted_price_lst_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
      String original_price_removecurrencysymbol = Original_price.get(i).getText().substring(1,Original_price.get(i).getText().length());
       String discount_price_removecurrencysymbol = Discounted_price.get(i).getText().substring(1,Discounted_price.get(i).getText().length());
      System.out.println(original_price_removecurrencysymbol);
      System.out.println(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);
      int difference = Integer.parseInt(original_price_removecurrencysymbol) -Integer.parseInt(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);
        System.out.println("Difference is:"+difference);
                if(difference>=50)
        {

                    Product_list.get(i).click();
                    // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'add_to_cart')]")).click();
        }
  }
        }       
}


error as>>

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 59, Size: 59
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Tekbakertest.Ted_sale.main(Ted_sale.java:92)
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqQSY.jpg
```

Comment: The condition is `i<Discounted_price.size()`, the action is `Original_price.get(i)`. Do you see the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

[image: product with out any discounts]

**For Error you are getting,** Please check the image. there is actually a product that doesn't have any discount price. Hence there is difference between sizes of discount prices and original prices array. you need to add some sort of validation before adding prices to the array(say if discount price element doesn't exists then add zero to that particular discounted price).

**Now coming to your real question**, the reason why it is not clicking then name of the product is because you are clicking the heading. try this code,

```
Product_list.get(i).findElement(By.tagName(a)).click();
```

let me know if this works.

Comment: yes ,it is adding only one product into the cart,unable to identify remaing products.e.g. if there are 4 product whose price difference is >50 then it is taking 1st one.